# JSON - JavaScript get nested value

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have this in JavaScript object taken from a Firebase query.

```
{
    "player": {
        "player:616320": {
            "skills": {
                "main": {
                    "attack": 1,
                    "defence": 1
                }
            },
            "uid": "player:616320",
            "username": "test1",
            "x": 1,
            "y": 1
        }
    }
}

var data = snap.val();
```

I can do `data.username` to get `test1`... but how would I go further? I tried searching `JSON` nesting and ... it was complicated.

And `snap.val()` is the `JSON` `object` above. How ould I get the `attack` from `main`?

Comment: Well if `data` is the whole object then `data.username` won't work - you'd need `data.player["player:616320"].username`

Comment: If `data.username` gives you `test1`, then `data` is probably `player:616320` in the tree. To get the value of `attack` I would think you can use `data.skills.main.attack`.

Comment: If `data.username` works then the rest is of the same format. As in `data.skills.main.attack` to get the value `1`. Basically just add `.` and whatever keys you want or you want to go into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case it would be:

```
obj.player["player:616320"].skills.main.attack
```

Where `obj` is the JSON object.

It's a tree where after the `.` is the child like so: `parent.child`. When there is a value that can't be represented normally you need to do `parent["some-Value"]`.

In your case it seems that `playerData` is actually the value of `obj.player["player:616320"]` and not the entire JSON object. In that case the same concept applies:

```
playerData.skills.main.attack
```

Comment: `parent["some-value"]` would have been a better example :)

Comment: I got it using this based off your answer: `playerData.skills['main']['attack']`

Comment: @DanF Great! You actually can just do `main.attack` other than `['main']['attack']`, but either way will work fine.